# javascript checkboxのnameの値を取得する

Tags: javascript

以下のようなhtmlでチェックボックスがチェックされた際にnameの値を取得するには、どのようなコードで実現できますでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示ください。

```
<div id="size-category-tab-22" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="size-category-checkbox-section">
        <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-2">
            <label class="size-labels">
              <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="78" display-name="7 - 8"> 7 - 8
            </label>
            <label class="size-labels">
              <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="910" display-name="9 - 10"> 9 - 10
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-3">
            <label class="size-labels">
              <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="1112" display-name="11 - 12"> 11 - 12
            </label>
            <label class="size-labels">
              <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="131" display-name="13 - 1"> 13 - 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-4">
            <label class="size-labels">
              <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="23" display-name="2 - 3"> 2 - 3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="size-category-add-section"> </div>
    <div class="size-category-size-chart"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: どのようなコードを書き、どのようにうまくいきませんでしたか？

Answer (score 1):

「input」タグのリストを取得します：

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

オブジェクトごとに、その「type」とその"checked"プロパティをチェック:

```
if (checkboxes[i].type === "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked) {
```

例えば、値が表示されます以下は、ボタンがクリックされたとき：

```js
function displayChecked() {

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var log = document.getElementById('log');
  log.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].type === "checkbox" && checkboxes[i].checked) {
      var name = checkboxes[i].name;
      log.innerHTML += "<li>" + "checkboxのnameの値は : " + name + "</li>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="size-category-tab-22" class="tab-pane">
  <div class="size-category-checkbox-section">
    <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-2">
      <label class="size-labels">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="78" display-name="7 - 8"> 7 - 8
      </label>
      <label class="size-labels">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="910" display-name="9 - 10"> 9 - 10
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-3">
      <label class="size-labels">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="1112" display-name="11 - 12"> 11 - 12
      </label>
      <label class="size-labels">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="131" display-name="13 - 1"> 13 - 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="size-category-column" id="size-category-column-4">
      <label class="size-labels">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sizes-row-checkbox" name="23" display-name="2 - 3"> 2 - 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="size-category-add-section"> </div>
  <div class="size-category-size-chart"> </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="チェックcheckboxのnameは？" onclick="displayChecked()" />
  <ul id="log">
  </ul>
</div>
```